# How to get user profile details in azure ad b2c

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure AD B2C authentication for my MVC web application. I have developed the sign-in part of the project. Now I want to get the user's details when a user logs into the web app. I have seen some of the articles which explain how to edit user details. But I couldn't find anything related to get user profile data. Please Help.

This is my SignIn action.

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" }, Startup.SignInPolicyId); 
        return Content("");
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect("~/Home/Login");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

**OPTION 1, PREFERRED - Use Azure AD B2C's Edit Profile functionality**

1. [Create an Edit Profile Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-profile-editing-policy)
2. Add [logic on the RedirectToIdentityProvider handler](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L86-L98) to override the policy when calling out to Azure AD B2C

```
    /*
     *  On each call to Azure AD B2C, check if a policy (e.g. the profile edit or password reset policy) has been specified in the OWIN context.
     *  If so, use that policy when making the call. Also, don't request a code (since it won't be needed).
     */
    private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(DefaultPolicy))
        {
            notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.Replace(DefaultPolicy, policy);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

3. Create your [EditProfile controller action](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L30-L46) ensuring it indicates that the EditProfilePolicy should be used:

```
    public void EditProfile()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Let the middleware know you are trying to use the edit profile policy (see OnRedirectToIdentityProvider in Startup.Auth.cs)
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Startup.EditProfilePolicyId);

            // Set the page to redirect to after editing the profile
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" };              HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);
            return;
        }
        Response.Redirect("/");
    }
```

**OPTION 2 - Implement your own Edit Profile screen and experience**
I won't go into the details of this option as this is quite lengthy but at a high level you would need to:

1. Implement your own screen
2. Implement your own API secured by Azure AD B2C (meaning that it requires and Azure AD B2C access token) and have this API [use Client Credentials to update the user in question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Answer (score -1):

Within the B2C policy you need to add claims.

Select the policy -> Edit -> Application Claims -> Select the ones you want -> save.

When a use signs in, these will be added to their token. You can then enumerate them within your code after they have logged in.:

```
var claimsIdentity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
{
     // do stuff with claim.Type & claim.Value
}
```