# .NET Core using Azure B2C Authentication, looking for the User Attributes such as @User.Identity.UserID after logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using .NET Core, with Azure B2C Authentication. On the project I'm developing, I can find the @User.Identity.Name, but I cant find the C# object name/path for the other "built in" User Attributes such as @User.Identity.UserID , @User.Identity.firstTimeLogging, @User.Identity.firstName. These Attribute are enabled in Azure AD. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you checked the access_token/id_token ? could you past a sample please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access custom claims by including them in the token sent to the app or by querying the Azure AD Graph API (not the Microsoft Graph yet).

- For the first option reading it from claim , you can follow below thread :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43996372/6049604

- For the other option , using graph api to get user details , you can browse the below doc for the same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications

Additional reference:

https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet/blob/master/B2CGraphClient/Program.cs

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your links were very helpful, I will post my solution below. Thanks

Comment: Glad to know it helped, feel free to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mohit, this is the solution I found.

```
var claimsIdentity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;

 List<String> termsList = new List<String>();
    foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
    {
        termsList.Add(claim.Value);
    }
   //The 2nd item in the claim is the objectidentifier
    Debug.WriteLine(termsList[2]); 
// there is probably a cleaner way, but it works for me.
```